# Writing a function that takes in an array of strings and returns a double, producing the average length of those strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So I'm practicing for a test that is coming up, and I'm stumped on one of my questions. This is a two part question, I'll include both questions first.

1) Create a function that takes in an array of strings and returns a double. This double will represent the average length of all the strings.

2) Create a MAIN function that asks the user for 10 strings. Once the array is filled, call the function from Question 1 to calculate the average length of the strings and output the result to the console.

Here is my code so far:

```
void avg(std::string averages[], int size) {

    double sum = 0;

    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++) {

        sum += averages[index]; // Error here, invalid operands to binary expression?

    }

    double retVal = sum / size;
    return retVal; //**I am getting an error here: void function avg should not return a value

}

int main() {

    std:: string myArray[10];
    std:: cout << "Please enter 10 strings...";

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::cin >>myArray[i];

    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What question do you have about this task or about the code you've written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum` is an integer. You have defined `averages` as an array of strings; you can't add strings to integers. Try

```
sum += averages[index].length();
```

Also, your comment later "I am getting an error here: void function avg should not return a value"... well the error message is telling you exactly what the problem is; your function is defined as

```
void avg(std::string averages[], int size) {
...
}
```

The type declared before the function name is its 'return type'. The keyword 'void' simply means 'this function doesn't return a value', so it is then getting confused when you try to use the `return` keyword to actually return a value. Change it to

```
double avg(std::string averages[], int size) {
...
}
```

**Edit**

To call the function, your `main()` should look like this. I've not tested this but it *should* work.

```
int main() {
   std::string myArray[10];
   std::cout << "Please enter 10 strings...\n";

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      std::getLine(std::cin, myArray[i]);
   }

   std::cout << avg(myArray, 10) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly... My last question is this: how would I call this avg function in the main function in order to calculate the average of the 10 strings that the user enters?